# Wordpress: Require wp-blog-header "Object of class LocaleMap could not be converted to string" in l10n.php

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I'm trying to add a wordpress blog to a company website. I've got my website files in the folder **mySite** in **rootFolder**. I've installed wordpress in another folder called **wordpress** in that same rootFolder. Using xampp I have changed *DocumentRoot* & *< Directory>* in **httpd.config** from *htdocs* to my rootFolder.

I've created a new file called blog.php in the **mySite** folder.
When I try to run `<?php require('../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');?>` on my blog page (localhost/mySite/blog) I get this error message:

> **Catchable fatal error:** Object of class LocaleMap could not be converted to string in C:\ (...)\rootFolder\wordpress\wp-includes\l10n.php on line 558

The relevant code in **l10n.php** looks like this:

```
function load_default_textdomain( $locale = null ) {
if ( null === $locale ) {
    $locale = get_locale();
}

// Unload previously loaded strings so we can switch translations.
unload_textdomain( 'default' );

$return = load_textdomain( 'default', WP_LANG_DIR . "/$locale.mo" );
```

The last line being from where the fatal error originates, apparently.

I have no idea what the problem is here. Is it about the language settings or does it have something to do with the linking of the wp-blog-header.php? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, or if it only works for pages created from scratch with wp as its foundation? You are supposed to move about htaccess and the like, so I'm a little hesitant... 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've solved it.
It was one of our own global variables (used on the site) with the same name that replaced the $locale which wp-blog-header was looking for. Once I changed our own variable's name, things started working.